# viewpager with one listview into one fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using android studio. I am trying to have view-pager with 3 view. i use one fragment with alistview , but with different adapters (get some data from database). moving between pages will change the adapter, but same fragment. I am doing so to avoid having 3 fragments each with its data-adapter, that may use phone memory (memory optimization).

Question.. how to change adapter when page changes. I can get the event of viewpager page change, but where to set new adapter & is it really memory saving ?

```
     viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new usersmanageTabFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));



        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    }

                    Boolean first = true;

                    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                         if (first && positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
                            onPageSelected(0);
                            first = false;
                           }
                    }

                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        InitializeSwipemenu();
                        // Check if this is the page you want.
                        Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(position) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //       Fragment page = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                        // Button b= (Button)  page.getView().findViewById(R.id.button3w);
                        // b.setText("ssssssss");


                    }
                });

 private void InitializeSwipemenu() {
        Fragment page = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userslistview);
          custad = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Namet, Father);
        listView.setAdapter(custad);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another Stackoverflow thread. setting data-adapter should be set at the fragment level.

Thanks..